# Fullpage.js Disable moveSectionUp when using continuous scroll or looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

Just starting to use fullPage.js and loving it so far.
Anyhow, when implementing continuous and looping effect and you're on the first section, it allows the end-user to scroll up and land on the last section as well ... which is a problem when trying to tell a story to the user. Therefore I am just trying to disable the up scrolling, but have no idea how to do so.

I did some research and came across the moveSectionUp and tried disabling it but had not figure out how to. Can anyone familiar with fullPage.js help me out here?

Note: I am only hoping to disable it for the first section and the rest is free to scroll back and forth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fullpage.js function [`setAllowScrolling`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setallowscrollingboolean-directions) with the parameter `up` like so:

```
//disabling scrolling up
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
```

You can use it on the `afterRender` callback and the `afterLoad` to play with it, like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    continuousVertical: true,
    afterRender: function () {
        //disabling scrolling up on page load if we are in the 1st section
        if($('.fp-section.active').index('.fp-section') === 0){
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
        if (index !== 1) {
            //activating the scrolling up for any other section
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'up');
        } else {
            //disabling the scrolling up when reaching 1st section
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/501/)

This way the visitors won't be able to scroll up on page load.

From the docs:

> **setAllowScrolling(boolean, [directions])**
>
> Adds or remove the possibility of scrolling through sections by using
>   the mouse wheel/trackpad or touch gestures (which is active by
>   default).
>
> directions: (optional parameter) Admitted values: all, up, down, left,
>   right or a combination of them separated by commas like down, right.
>   It defines the direction for which the scrolling will be enabled or
>   disabled.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the detailed demo too. I was forced to use the loopBottom for the effect. Anyhow, I was also trying to figure out how to create sections within slides?

Comment: @ElizabethChau268 that's not possible. Although if you really need It I could customize the plugin for you for some price.

Comment: that's wonderful. But currently I don't need the effect just yet. I was just brainstorming some ideas and figuring out if that is possible. I will let you know if customization is needed. Thanks Again!